# Replace a substring that comes after a pattern in a string in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have a string like 
`"/fixed_string1/{random_string1}/fixed_string2/fixed_string3"`

I need to replace the random_string1 to some other.

The result that I need should look like this 
`"/fixed_string1/{random_string2}/fixed_string2/fixed_string3"`

The `random_string2` is known while the `random_string1` is unknown.

Can anyone give a suggestion using javascript regex.

Comment: Please add, what you have already tried.

Comment: show some code or attempts and we can help you learn. This shows you just want an answer for your work instead of help.

Answer (score 2):

So match the part you know

```js
    var str = "/fixed_string1/{random_string1}/fixed_string2/fixed_string3";
    var updated = str.replace(/(\/fixed_string1\/)[^\/]*/,"$1foobar");
    console.log(updated)
```

or you can split it into an array, replace the index, and join it back together

```js
    var str = "/fixed_string1/{random_string1}/fixed_string2/fixed_string3";
    var parts = str.split("/");
    parts[2] = "foobar"
    var updated = parts.join("/");
    console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var string = "/fixed_string1/{random_string1}/fixed_string2/fixed_string3";
var regex = / *\{[^)]*\} */g; 
string = string.replace(regex, "$1 ###ADDED TEXT### $3");
console.log(string);
```